# How to check if an element in an array subtracted from another element will equal a third element

Tags: c++

```
int values[] = {5, 10, 15, 20};
```

In the array above print out
15 10 5 because 15-10 = 5

and 20 15 5 because 20-15=5

```
 for (int i=0; i<maxLength; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<maxLength; j++) {
            for (int v=j+1; v<maxLength; v++){

            }
```

I was thinking about a triple loop but I do not know how I am not sure on how to program it and output the answer

Comment: Could you show your attempts as you've posted a problem that could be solved in any number of ways

Comment: A hint: use an helping function, that tests if a given value belongs to an array

Comment: Do you know how to get a value out of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brute force variant:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int values[] = {5, 10, 15, 20};
    for(const auto& a : values) {
        for(const auto& b : values) {
            if(&b==&a) continue; // skip if we have the same element in a and b
            for(const auto& x : values) {
                if(&x==&a || &x==&b) continue; // skip if x is the same element as either a or b
                if(a-b==x) std::cout << a << "-" << b << "=" << x << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
15-5=10
15-10=5
20-5=15
20-15=5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not any standard algorithm if you ask about that. IMO you should write your own algorithm or try to find some help with google.

My first simple idea (for sure it is not optimal)

```
std::vector<int> values = {5, 10, 15, 20};

for(auto first = values.begin(); first < values.end(); ++first){
    for(auto second = values.begin(); second < values.end(); ++second) {
        if(first != second) {
            for(auto result = values.begin(); result < values.end(); ++result) {
                if(result != first && result != second && *result == *first - *second) 
                    return true;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: First optimization you can think of is to not checking same number multiple times.